# How to create a single ID across separate entity IDs based on shared attributes using SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, duplicates, primary-key

**Background**: I have a SQL table that contains acct_ids and the component_ids, which indicate the component parts used by each account. Accounts can have multiple components, and the same component can be used by multiple accounts.

**Objective**: I would like to 'dedupe' acct_ids based on shared component_ids; so if any acct_id shares any component_id with any other acct_id, combine those into a single new id. I'm using BigQuery SQL to do this.

Here is a sample of the data table:

```
+---------+--------------+
| acct_id | component_id |
+---------+--------------+
|       1 | A            |
|       1 | B            |
|       1 | C            |
|       2 | C            |
|       2 | D            |
|       2 | E            |
|       3 | G            |
|       3 | E            |
|       3 | F            |
|       4 | H            |
|       4 | I            |
|       5 | H            |
|       5 | J            |
+---------+--------------+
```

For instance, acct_ids 1 and 2 share component_id C and acct_ids 2 and 3 share component_id E, so all 3 of these acct_ids shoud be labeled with a single, shared id (new_id = 1). Similarly, acct_ids 4 and 5 share component_id H, so both of these acct_ids should be labeled with a single, shared id (new_id = 2).

For the sample data above, the desired output would be:

```
+---------+--------------+--------+
| acct_id | component_id | new_id |
+---------+--------------+--------+
|       1 | A            |      1 |
|       1 | B            |      1 |
|       1 | C            |      1 |
|       2 | C            |      1 |
|       2 | D            |      1 |
|       2 | E            |      1 |
|       3 | G            |      1 |
|       3 | E            |      1 |
|       3 | F            |      1 |
|       4 | H            |      2 |
|       4 | I            |      2 |
|       5 | H            |      2 |
|       5 | J            |      2 |
+---------+--------------+--------+
```

I've been thinking through ways to tackle this - perhaps an approach incorporating `FULL OUTER JOIN` is where to start, but I haven't been able to build a cohesive query that gets there yet.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use syntax

```
CASE <field_name> WHEN <value> THEN <new_walue>
```

I did try it in BigQuery on my data and following works for me:

```
SELECT 
CASE component_id
WHEN 'A' THEN '1'
WHEN 'B' THEN '1'
WHEN 'J' THEN '2'
ELSE '0'
END AS new_component_id, *
FROM `<project>.<dataset>.<table>` LIMIT 1000
```

You may be also interested in reading [documentation for conditional expressions in Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions)

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
DECLARE rows_count, run_away_stop INT64 DEFAULT 0;

CREATE TEMP TABLE ttt AS 
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(component_id ORDER BY component_id) arr 
FROM `project.dataset.your_table`
GROUP BY acct_id;

LOOP
  SET rows_count = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ttt);
  SET run_away_stop = run_away_stop + 1;

  CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE ttt AS
  SELECT ANY_VALUE(arr) arr FROM (
    SELECT ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT val FROM UNNEST(arr) val ORDER BY val) arr
    FROM (
      SELECT ANY_VALUE(arr1) arr1, ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(arr) arr    
      FROM (
        SELECT t1.arr arr1, t2.arr arr2, ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT val FROM UNNEST(ARRAY_CONCAT( t1.arr, t2.arr)) val ORDER BY val) arr 
        FROM ttt t1, ttt t2 
        WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(t1.arr) val JOIN UNNEST(t2.arr) val USING(val)) > 0
      ) GROUP BY FORMAT('%t', arr1)
    )
  ) GROUP BY FORMAT('%t', arr);

  IF (rows_count = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ttt) AND run_away_stop > 1) OR run_away_stop > 10 THEN BREAK; END IF;
END LOOP;

SELECT acct_id, component_id, new_id FROM `project.dataset.your_table` 
JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() new_id, arr FROM ttt) 
ON component_id IN UNNEST(arr);
```

As you can see - above is using recently introduced [scripting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting) feature and if to apply to sample data from your question the final output is

```
Row acct_id component_id    new_id   
1   1       A               2    
2   1       B               2    
3   1       C               2    
4   2       C               2    
5   2       D               2    
6   2       E               2    
7   3       E               2    
8   3       F               2    
9   3       G               2    
10  4       H               1    
11  4       I               1    
12  5       H               1    
13  5       J               1
```

When applying to real data - make sure you set appropriate max for run_away_stop (in above script it is 10 - see last statement within LOOP)

Btw, you can test, play with above using below "playground" which mimics sample data from your question

```
DECLARE rows_count, run_away_stop INT64 DEFAULT 0;

CREATE TEMP TABLE input AS (
  SELECT 1 acct_id, 'A' component_id UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'B' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'C' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'C' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'D' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'E' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'G' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'E' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'F' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'H' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'I' UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'H' UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'J' 
);

CREATE TEMP TABLE ttt AS 
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(component_id ORDER BY component_id) arr 
FROM input
GROUP BY acct_id;

LOOP
  SET rows_count = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ttt);
  SET run_away_stop = run_away_stop + 1;

  CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE ttt AS
  SELECT ANY_VALUE(arr) arr FROM (
    SELECT ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT val FROM UNNEST(arr) val ORDER BY val) arr
    FROM (
      SELECT ANY_VALUE(arr1) arr1, ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(arr) arr    
      FROM (
        SELECT t1.arr arr1, t2.arr arr2, ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT val FROM UNNEST(ARRAY_CONCAT( t1.arr, t2.arr)) val ORDER BY val) arr 
        FROM ttt t1, ttt t2 
        WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(t1.arr) val JOIN UNNEST(t2.arr) val USING(val)) > 0
      ) GROUP BY FORMAT('%t', arr1)
    )
  ) GROUP BY FORMAT('%t', arr);

  IF (rows_count = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ttt) AND run_away_stop > 1) OR run_away_stop > 10 THEN BREAK; END IF;
END LOOP;

SELECT acct_id, component_id, new_id FROM input 
JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() new_id, arr FROM ttt) 
ON component_id IN UNNEST(arr) 
ORDER BY acct_id, component_id;
```